# Function called from webapp does not send email

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm having a problem with Google Scripts.

I'm trying to do an open questionnaire that allows anonymous file uploads to a specific folder on my Google Drive, and afterwards sends me a notification email to my mail. It uploads the file fine, but the email is not sent.

In debugging mode, it sent the email.

Here is my code:

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Su Nombre..">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Subir Archivo" 
           onclick="this.value='subiendo..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">
</form>
```

And the Google Script file:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {
  try {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(/*folder id*/);
    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);     

    file.setDescription("Subido Por " + form.myName);

    // email
    var asunto = "Testing attaching file";
    var correo = /*my email address*/;
    var options = {attachment : [form.MyFile]};    

    MailApp.sendEmail(correo, asunto, emailBody, options);

    return "Archivo Subido Con Exito " + file.getUrl();
  } 
  catch (error) { 
     return error.toString(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Which URL are you testing your functionality with? One that ends with `/exec`? Or with `/dev`? Note that `/exec` requires you to publish your current script state (e.g. HEAD) as a new version, while `/dev` executes the current HEAD state, even if it differs from the most recently published version.

Comment: I m using fue creare mes web app feature frontera Google apps script